# Detecting the popping of a modal when the user performs a back gesture in MAUI Android app (MVVM structure)

Tags: android, mvvm, modal-dialog, maui, gesture

I am developing a MAUi Android app using the MVVM structure, and I'm facing difficulty in detecting when a modal is popped due to a back gesture performed by the user.

In my app, I have implemented a Modal dialogue that can be dismissed either by clicking a cancel button or through a back gesture (e.g., swipe left). When the cancel button is clicked, I can easily handle the dismissal event. However, I am unsure how to detect when the user performs a back gesture to pop the modal.

Could anyone please provide guidance on how to detect when the user performs a back gesture to pop the modal, while considering the MVVM structure? I need to perform certain actions when the modal is popped, regardless of how it was dismissed. Thank you in advance for your assistance!

I have already tried using the <Shell.BackButtonBehavior> approach, but it did not work as expected. The back gesture does not trigger the desired behavior.

Comment: Maybe [Page.Disappearing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.maui.controls.page.disappearing?view=net-maui-7.0) on the modal page.

Comment: The back gesture will not call the page's back button pressed event but call the android activity's key down event.